# experiencing "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" with hardhat mainnet fork, when calling contract names on chain

Tags: solidity, hardhat, mainnet, test

I am trying to test my contract against mainnet using the hardhat fork mechanism,
I am using alchemy as my network provider and trying to retrieve the contract names from mainnet
after creating ERC721 contract objects in the solidity contract. When I run a test to see if I can fetch the names onchain,
I seem to experience an error:
`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

There are no recurrsions from what I can see in the code, would anyone have any suggestions as to what else this error could indicate?

I would greatly appreciate any input on this.
hardhat fork config

```
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: MAINNET_RPC_URL,
        blockNumber: 11095000,
      },
    }
```

contract objects created here

```
        for (uint i=1; i< _preSaleOneArray.length; i++){
            preSaleOneTokenMap[_preSaleOneTokenNames[i]] = preSaleTokenStruct(ERC721(_preSaleOneArray[i]),1,false);
        }
```

retrieval of the mainnet contract names

```
    function getNameOfContractPreSaleOne(string calldata name) public view returns (string memory){
        ERC721 _token = preSaleOneTokenMap[name]._contractObj;
        return _token.name();
    }
```

Test case

```
  it("should show presale day one contract names on mainnet", async function () {
    console.log(
      await contract.getNameOfContractPreSaleOne(preSaleDayOneTokenNames[0])
    );
  });
```

Error:

```
       should show presale day one contract names on mainnet:
     RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at spelunk (node_modules\ethers\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:26:5)
      at spelunk (node_modules\ethers\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:36:28)
      at spelunk (node_modules\ethers\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:36:28)
      at spelunk (node_modules\ethers\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:36:28)
```

Full Source code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W5W4M9c94kWUQMDf5MiI8814dKp0sxVJk6mFt7MUgtY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, you can share all your smart contract code

Comment: I have added a google docs link, [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W5W4M9c94kWUQMDf5MiI8814dKp0sxVJk6mFt7MUgtY/edit?usp=sharing], thanks for taking a look